# React on prod env and registerServiceWorker.js error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, service-worker

So, I compiled my react app and moved it to AWS S3 bucket. I launched the static server and the everything is working as it should, but... I´m seeing an error in the console:

```
Error during service worker registration: > DOMException: The operation is insecure.  registerServiceWorker.js:80:6
```

I don´t have that error in my local env. I researched and found that the error was related to the use of HTTP. Is that right...? My concern, at this point, is double...

1. Error should be blocking the service worker API which is a nice-to-have cache.
2. Is also there a functional or security related issue...?

I´m new with React. This is my first time moving one of my practices to prod and could not find useful info about this error.
Any info will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firefox please go to [Privacy & Security](http://about:preferences#privacy), under History make sure you keep the cookies until they expire.

It is a bug in Firefox 59.
[image]

Comment: I'm using Firefox 69 and this behavior still persists. Instead of allow cookies from all sites to be kept, you can narrow this permission by adding an exception to alow `http://localhost:3000`.